# Как появилось слово "вертлюг"?

Tags: этимология

*…Вы бы обрадовались несказанно и охотно бы подверглись опасности лишиться вместе с сапогом и собственной вашей ноги вплоть до самого **вертлюга…***

(И. С. Тургенев, «Бурмистр», 1847)

Нашла в словарях значения слова; нашла синонимы: *антабка, звено, вертел, вертлюжок, трохантин*; а вот истории возникновения - не нашла.

Поделитесь своими знаниями: каким образом в русском языке появился **вертлюг**?

Answer (score 3):

Вертлюг - родственник вертелу, и оба восходят к глаголу "вертеть".

**[Этимологический словарь Крылова](http://www.endic.ru/krylov/Vertel-2455.html)**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[До странности много вещей называют яблоками. В анатомии - яблоко берцовой кости, или вертлюг (от "вертеть")...](http://slovnik.narod.ru/etim_prikl6.htm)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Этимология слова "вертеть" по Максу Фасмеру:](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C)

> Происходит от праслав. *vьrtěti, от кот. в числе прочего произошли:
>   ст.-слав. врьтѣти, врьштѫ (др.-греч. κυκλοῦν), русск. вертеть, укр.
>   вертіти, болг. врътя́, сербохорв. вр́тjети, словенск. vrtéti,
>   др.-чешск. vrtět, словацк. vrteť, польск. wiercieć, в.-луж. wjerćić,
>   н.-луж. wjerśeś...

Comment: Да, я предполагала, что "верт/люг" образовался от "вертеть", но не стала озвучивать эту гипотезу в своём вопросе. Почему? Потому что есть концовка "люг",  которой больше ни в одном русском слове нет ( во всяком случае, я - не нашла ). Откуда она взялась? По Фармеру этого не видно.

Comment: Ну, наш фермер занимался глаголом "вертеть", а не его производными! Про концовку можно спросить; "люг" может оказаться унификсом.

Answer (score 2):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При том, что упоминается *шарнир*, речь может идти, в том числе, и о главном шарнире, где нога прикрепляется к тазу.